# Placing Gtk.Widget in Box with top padding

Tags: python, gtk3, pygtk

I have a box like this:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk
[...]
box_outer = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL, spacing=0)
box_outer.pack_start(Gtk.Label('Label1'), False, False, 100)
box_outer.pack_start(Gtk.Label('Label2'), False, False, 0)
```

I want the first label to be 100 pixels from the top. The second label should be directly under it. As I found out, the padding parameter always sets the padding for all four directions. How can I set it for only one direction?

Comment: By the way, the fourth parameter specifies *spacing* not padding

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `Widget.set_margin_top()` for margin (instead of padding or spacing) at the top of a widget.

https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/Widget.html#Gtk.Widget.set_margin_top

So instead of

```
box_outer.pack_start(Gtk.Label('Label1'), False, False, 100)
```

you'd use

```
label = Gtk.Label('Label1')
label.set_margin_top(100)
box_outer.pack_start(label, False, False, 0)
```

Comment: Glad, I found this. The opposite is `label.set_margin_bottom(100)`